# What intent is used for navigation in Google Now?

Tags: android

I am trying to write an app that hooks into the "navigation to" functionality of Google Now but I am unable to figure out exactly how it works. I suspect it's using "Intent.ACTION_VIEW" and then passing it some special URL but I haven't been able to find any documentation on that. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into implicit intents.
Specifically for GPS navigation, you have a detailed explanation right here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#display_a_map

if you want to do something more specific, just ask :)

That "special URL" you are referring to is a URI (so the schema is geo, as opposed to a URL where the schema is usually http).

P.S. here's some material about implicit intents :
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html
and if you are in the process of learning the android framework, then I recommend Udacity's free course "developing Android Apps"- Google engineers explaining Android. That will save you a lot of time for sure!